# Slack Integration from Cypress dashboard without using CI

Tags: cypress, slack

If I run cypress test without passing record key locally it works but the results are not reflected on cypress dashboard even after setting a record key as environment variable in .env.json file whereas if run I run a test by passing record key in cli, results of test are reflected on cypress dashboard and it's notified on slack. so my concern is how do I set record key as environment variable so that I need not have to pass it through cli and how would the tests run on server and get recorded after setting a cron job?

contents of .env.json file:
{
"CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY": "recordkey provided from cypress"
}

cli command: npx cypress run

Comment: Can you provide more information, for example the contents of your .env.json, and the CLI command you are running?

Comment: .env.json file content is:
{
"CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY": "recordkey provided from cypress"
}

and I am running "node_modules/.bin/cypress run" command in cli all i want is to record tests in cypress dashboard

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but there is an option to pass the key as a command line parameter here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run